# how to append multiple string to an HTML element in jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, json

Here, using ajax call I am getting the data as json object. For example, in userid,  it returns some value. But in address value, it returns like addr1, addr2, addr3 (3 values). So how can I append these 3 values in html element and also it should be in String format `tostring()`

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $.ajax({
          type: "GET",
          url: "Controller?token=123",
          dataType: 'json',
          success: function(data){

          $('#userid').html(data.userid.toString());          
          $('#addr').html(data.addr1.append(addr2));
          },
          error:function(){
            alert("Sorry!");
          }
        });

});
</script>
```

Example strings:

addr1: 124, WELINGTONE STREET

addr2: NEWYORK

addr3: OH 12454-8787

These values are get from json object with the key names as addr1, addr2 and addr3
I need to append the key not values.

Comment: can you give an example of the string?

Comment: var add1=data.addr1.toString();var add2=data.addr2.toString();;var add3=data.addr3.toString(); And then do this :-  $('#addr').html(add1+','+add2+','+add3);

Comment: You could just directly mention/use the key as a string in your html. However any changes made to the key string needs alteration in JS.

Comment: how???can u pls explain?

Comment: Append the keys, not values? you sure you're asking the right question?

Answer (score -1):

Something like this?

`$('#addr').html([data.addr1,data.addr2,data.addr3].join("<br>"));`

Comment: I am getting the values but couldnt append it

Comment: If addr1-3 are strings, this will work absolutely fine.
I may have misunderstood you in what it is exactly you need to achieve, or you may not have explained it in enough detail...